# Passing a stack allocated argument by reference to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

I have a function say void theFunc(int num&, int* array) that takes in a an int by reference and an array pointer

```
theFunc(int num&, int* array)
{ array[0] = num; 
}
```

this is just an example, so the function does something simple

```
int main()
{ int k  = 3;
  int* theArray = new int[5];
  theFunc(k, theArray);

 delete[] theArray;
 return(0);
}
```

My question is how is k, a stack allocated int instance, passed by reference to theFunc and stored in a dynamically stored array. I know that objects/argument can't just move between the stack and heap because they have specific stored memory addresses. I want to understand why this works, and what is happening under the hood (also if there's a difference in this case from passing by value).

Thanks!

Comment: Stack variables have a memory address as well. The address is just passed to the function the same way a heap address would be.

Comment: Another key point is that the _value_ of `k` is being _copied_ into `array[0]`

Comment: `int num&` is a syntax error. Also `theFunc` must have a return type. Please post real code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that `k` is not being "stored" in the dynamically allocated array. Rather, when you write `int *theArray = new int[5]` you are allocating a block of memory that can hold an array of five integers. In fact it already *does* hold five integers: having done nothing else, `theArray[0]` is a valid expression, i.e., it is an integer, although its value might be `-32,768` or something like that. When you call `theFunc` with a reference to `k`, you are changing the value of `theArray[0]` to `k` by *copy assignment*, so you are assigning the value of `k` to the first element of the array. You are not storing anything new, you are just changing the value of something that has been already stored.

Indeed, in this particular case nothing is gained or lost by passing `num` by reference. The observable behavior of the function as written would be identical if it were passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable K exists on the stack, which is just a chunk of memory that the program is using. So every stack entry still exists as an addressable memory location.

When you call theFunc, that address of K is pushed onto the call stack, and popped off in theFunc. When you do the assignment to the array location, the value of num (or K), meaning the value at the address that was passed in, is copied into the array.

In this case, passing by value would have the same effect since theFunc isn't changing num (or K).